# Selenium Webdriver error "The method sendKeys(CharSequence...) from the type WebElement refers to the missing type CharSequence"

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using java "1.8.0_131" with selenium webdriver 2.53.1 in MyEclipse Enterprise workbench. i have followed all the procedures and have added all the necessary jars required but when i am trying to use "sendKeys" function, it is showing following error:

> The method sendKeys(CharSequence...) from the type WebElement refers to the missing type CharSequence.

Can anyone please help regarding this issue?

Following is my code:

Comment: Can you give us the code that throws this err?

Comment: @VikasKumar Can you consider showcasing your work; Selenium/WebDriver type/version and Browser type/version please? Thanks

Comment: @santhoshkumar 

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FindingWebElements { 
public static void main(String[] args) {
  
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
  
  String appurl="http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/automation-practice-form/";
  
driver.get(appurl);
WebElement firstname=driver.findElement(By.name("firstname"));
firstname.sendKeys("Vikas");

 }

}

Comment: @DebanjanB, Selenium/Webdriver type- java and Version= selenium-java-2.53.1,     Browser- Firefox (Version- 47.0.2)

Comment: @VikasKumar Try bumping up your Selenium to 3.4.0, geckodriver v0.17.0 & Mozilla Firefox to 53.0. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB, Initially, i was using this configuration but the firefox was not launching with this configuration. Thats why i moved to Selenium 2.

Comment: The exact code that you have written works good in my machine. I suggest you to use java 1.8, selenium 3.4, Latest firefox and Gecko driver. If you have any issues while doing tell, kindly let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

1. Remove all those jars
2. download the [selenium-server-standalone](https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar) jar
3. Add to the eclipse -> `Project -> right click -> Build Path -> Configure build Path - Add External Jars -> (once added) Up`  (it should be in top)
4. Run a simple test as you did.
5. Add additional jars one by one - below the `selenium-server-standalone`